# edit timer made in a main form via sub form in c#

Tags: c#, forms, timer

I have a timer in the main form, yet I want to change the interval of the timer via the second sub form. However, the within the subform there is a 'System.NullReferenceException' upon taking the textbox text, the code is visible below. Any suggestions, examples, tips or help will be much appreciated.

Main Form with the timer (added via designer);

```
public partial class Booyaa : Form
{
    private void Booyaa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BooyaaTimer.Interval = 45 * 60 * 1000); // 45 mins
        BooyaaTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(BooyaaTimer_Tick);
        BooyaaTimer.Start();

        if (!Properties.Settings.Default.SettingShutdown)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Time");
            GetPass pass = new GetPass();
            DialogResult result = pass.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
            { 
                Properties.Settings.Default.SettingShutdown = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other sub form for timer control:

```
public partial class TimerControl : Form
{
    public static Timer BooyaaTimer { get; internal set; }           

    public TimerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();               
    }

    private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BooyaaTimer.Interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);    
    }
}
```

Comment: BooyaaTimer is always null, you aren't initializing it.

Comment: When posting questions about exceptions, you should say what exception you're getting.

Comment: @Gusman how can i fix it ?

Comment: @RufusL  sorry my bad, I've edited it. It was a 'System.NullReferenceException'

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @gusman, check in the main form `Booyaa` form to make sure `BooyaaTimer` is there (that is it is not null). If you did not drag-drop timer control on to form the please make sure you call `BooyaaTimer = new Timer()` in form's constructor.

So if things are alright till here, you are not passing timer to the sub-form. If **`GetPass`** is actually *`TimerControl`* (which I suspect), then you need to modify `Booyaa_Load` call like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Time");
GetPass pass = new GetPass();
/*****-----------******/
pass.BooyaaTimer = BooyaaTimer;//set sub-form's property

DialogResult result = pass.ShowDialog();
```

Also, in sub-form it does not hurt to check for nulls before using the objects that will be set from some other place.

```
if(BooyaaTimer!=null)
  BooyaaTimer.Interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Next, try using int.TryParse.